# unix pipe command mix with find

Tags: exec, pipe

To get file names which contains the word 'measure_remove' in 'compact' directory,
I made this command.

> find ./compact/ -type f -exec grep -n 'measure_remove' {} \ -exec ls {} \;

- grep: ls: 'there are no such file or directory'
- grep:  -exec: 'there are no such file or directory'
- **./compact/prepare.js:44509: = "measure_remove";**
- grep: ls: 'there are no such file or directory'
- grep:  -exec: 'there are no such file or directory'

It works but i just want to get file names and result.
is there more than one way?

Comment: Use grep -l......................                 .

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the filenames that match, pass -l (el) to grep:

```
$ find compact -type f -exec grep -l 'measure_remove' {} \;
```

If you also want the line matches, some grep accept -H, but all grep should print the file name if you give it 2 file names.  A common technique is to pass /dev/null as a second file to search:

```
$ find compact -type f -exec grep -n measure_remove /dev/null {} \;
```